# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject ,all Object

Tags: .net, json.net

i can't print `p.paper`, `p.pen`, `p.eraser`, `p.box`.  the reason : 
 
1. maybe class RootObject is wrong definition, how to fix ?   
 
2. JSON input could be change  `1 row, 3 row` or more than `2163`row , how can I handle all the case ? I want to get data from not only 1 row but also 2163 rows

can anyone know and teach me ?
thanks a lot

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    //JsonResult is JSON string , input could be
    //{"total":1,"row":{"1":{"paper":"2330","pen":"","eraser":"","box":""}}}
    //or
    //{"total":3,"row":{"1":
    //{"paper":"0050","pen":"","eraser":"","box":""},"2":
    //{"paper":"0051","pen":"","eraser":"","box":""},"3":
    //{"paper":"0052","pen":"","eraser":"","box":""}}}
    //or
    //{"total":2163,"row":{"1":
    //{"paper":"0050","pen":"","eraser":"","box":""},"2":
    //{"paper":"0051","pen":"","eraser":"","box":""},"3":
    //{"paper":"0052","pen":"","eraser":"","box":""},.................}}

     RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(JsonResult);

      foreach (productType p in root.Contents)
      {
           Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3})", p.paper, 
           p.pen, p.eraser, p.box));
      }
```

}

```
public class productType
{
     public string paper  { get; set; }
     public string pen { get; set; }
     public string eraser { get; set; }
     public string box { get; set; }
 }    

 public class RootObject
 {
      [JsonProperty("row")]
      public productType[] Contents { get; set; }

      public int total { get; set; }    
  }
```

Comment: Your JSON is misrepresenting what-should-have-been-an-array as named objects, with the property names being numeric strings. It will be hard to deserialize this because in C#, property names can't be numbers (or even start with a number). See the last part of the answer by **aloisdg** for what your JSON should look like. I hope you can change it to look like that, or else you may not succeed.

Comment: @PeterB It is actually not hard at all to deserialize this JSON.  Just use a Dictionary instead of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your JSON is structured, the rows are actually represented as an object with numbered properties rather than an array.  You can handle this in your `RootObject` class by using a `Dictionary<string, productType>` instead of a `productType[]`.  The keys of the dictionary will be the row numbers.  This will work for any number of rows.

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("row")]
    public Dictionary<string, productType> Contents { get; set; }

    public int total { get; set; }    
}
```

Here is a demo with 3 rows: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dwX4RI

Comment: Dear Brian Rogers, thank you . I will try Dictionary<string, productType> in work ,thanks.

Comment: Brian Rogers 's answer to solve my problem . it can work . thanks !

Answer (score 1):

A C# class cant start with a number. You could rely on `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "1")]` to map `1` to `productType`, but it will only work for `1`. It is not a solution.

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "1")]
public class productType
{
    public string paper { get; set; }
    public string pen { get; set; }
    public string eraser { get; set; }
    public string box { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    public productType productType { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int total { get; set; }
    public Row row { get; set; }
}
```

So what?

**Your JSON is your problem.** `row` should be `rows` and be an array of item. Something like:

```
{"total":3,"rows":[
{"paper":"0050","pen":"","eraser":"","box":""},
{"paper":"0051","pen":"","eraser":"","box":""},
{"paper":"0052","pen":"","eraser":"","box":""}]}
```

Comment: Dear aloisdg,  Thanks.  But, because l'm client, ask server for data, and the server just give me row not rows....